# dataBinding - DAO.recordset to MSDBGrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, dao, dbgrid

I am writing a program that use MSDBGrid (5.0) ActiveX interop COMObject and MSAccess DAO ActiveX COMObject.
using vb.net framework 4.7.2
Those things are too old, yes i know it, But i have to use it.

I need to bind data from DAO.RecordSet to DBGrid

```
Dim Rs_Tantousya As DAO.Recordset 
Dim Qd_Tantousya As DAO.QueryDef

Dim Rs As DAO.Recordset 
Dim Qd_Tantousya As DAO.QueryDef


Private Sub Open_TQuery()

    Qd = Db.QueryDefs(aMst)
    Rs = Qd.OpenRecordset()
    'Me.DataCtrl.Recordset = Rs

    'Dim col As MSDBGrid.Column
    'col = CTypeDynamic(Of MSDBGrid.Column)(Me.DBGrid1.get_Columns(1))
    'Me.DBGrid1.HoldFields()
    'Me.DBGrid1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource.RecordSet", Me.DataCtrl.Recordset, Nothing)
    'Me.DBGrid1.Refresh()

    Me.DBGrid1.DataSource.RecordSet = Me.DataCtrl.Recordset

    Qd.Close()
End Sub
```

I cant manage to set Me.DBGrid1.DataSource which return MSDBGrid.ICursor,
I used to try set Me.DBGrid1.DataSource.Recordset = Me.DataCtrl.Recordset, but it throw exception said Me.DBGrid1.DataSource is nothing.

I searched on the internet already, but it was all delphi and vb5, vb6 sample code... 
If you have any idea about how to do it or have a piece of sample code, pls leave a comment.
Thank you very much!

Comment: If you're using VB.NET, why are you using all VB6-technology?  Why not use ADO.NET and a `DataGridView`?

Comment: Thank you for reading, this is from an old program that we have to migrate from vb6 to .net, we about to move to MSSql and DataGridView, but firstly, the DBfile is from another team so for now, to run the program, we have to fix the code and run it on the old programs's ActiveX recources.
and 2ndly, I am really curious about it.